# How to make DNS queries on Linux (with python) bypassing nsswitch.conf and no additional packages

Tags: python, linux

I'd like to make DNS queries to check if some entries in the /etc/hosts file are obsolete (now working DNS) or conflicting with DNS answers. nsswitch.conf is configured to lookup /etc/hosts first.
gethostbyname() or getaddrinfo() will not work because they both use the OSes mechasnims (nsswitch.conf).

I know about the pythonDNS package. Unfortunatly it's rather difficult to install additional packages on the systems. Also, the python version available is rather old (python23).

The only possible solution I see so far is parsing nslookup or dig output. But I really don't like the idea because of the complexity involved (CNAMEs, multiple records,...).

I'm searching for a single class/function solution to make DNS A-Record Lookups.

Comment: Try http://www.dnspython.org/

Answer (score 1):

The obvious options:

- [PyDNS](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)
- Call res_query via the libresolv C API (e.g. using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes))

Answer (score 1):

[Twisted Names](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedNames) contains a DNS client.

Answer (score 0):

I always liked evdns

http://linux.die.net/man/3/evdns

There appears to be a python binding called pyevent

http://code.google.com/p/pyevent/source/browse/trunk/evdns.pxi?r=44

Comment: Hi Angelom, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly no additional software is possible on the systems. Stock RHEL4.8

Answer (score 0):

Is it impossible to install additional software because of technical limitations or because of policy?

If it's not policy you might be able to get somewhere with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)